# I want to separate Divs under one another

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page that you can scroll down with no side scrolling functions. I'm trying to add a new div container to create an About Me Section on the page but the text keeps going above the IntroDiv and creates a side scroll.

How do I fix it?

I tried using
`div.AboutMe {  left: 10%;     position: absolute;     padding: 50px; }`

so that the AboutMe section would place underneath the IntroDiv, but it wont work.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

/*This section is for the Navigation Bar*/

.navibar {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Styles the links in the Navigation Bar*/

.navibar a {
  float: right;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Poppins;
}


/*Change the colour of the links and transitions on hover*/

.navibar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline #F1F1F1;
  text-underline-offset: 0.5em;
  transition: 0s;
}


/*Adds decoration, colour, etc. to the active/current link being viewed*/

.navibar a.active {
  text-underline-offset: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: underline #DB6518;
}

body {
  background-color: #070707;
}

div.IntroBox {
  top: 25%;
  left: 10%;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 50px;
}

p.greet {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Poppins;
}

p.followupgreet {
  margin-top: -20;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #427FBA;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Poppins;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

p.followupgreet:hover {
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Firefox Transition out */
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Opera Transition out */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Safari and Google Chrome Transition out */
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Internet Explorer Transition out */
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Transition for All */
  color: #DB6518;
}

button.contactme {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #070707;
  border: 2px solid #F1F1F1;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  font-family: Poppins;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -5;
}

button.contactme:hover {
  background-color: #427FBA;
  border: 2px solid #366DA3;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Firefox Transition out */
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Opera Transition out */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Safari and Google Chrome Transition out */
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Internet Explorer Transition out */
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Transition for All */
}

img.icons {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 5;
  margin-right: 0;
}

img.icons:hover {
  filter: invert(50%) sepia(9%) saturate(2890%) hue-rotate(168deg) brightness(90%) contrast(93%);
}

p.followuppara {
  margin-top: -20;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: -10;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  font-family: Poppins;
}

div.AboutMe {
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <!-- script src="?.js"></script -->
    <!-- This is the JavaScript file name -->
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css" -->
    <!-- This is the CSS file name !-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Name Here || Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- HEADER BAR HERE !-->
  <div class="navibar">
    <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
    <a href="#link">Projects</a>
  </div>
    <!--INTRODUCTION BOX STARTS HERE!-->
    <div class="IntroBox">
      <p class="greet">Hello, my name is..</p>
      <br>
      <p class="followupgreet">Name Here</p>
      <br>
      <p class="followuppara">Welcome to my Journey of Web Development.</p>
      <!--INTRODUCTION BOX END HERE!-->

      <!-- Button Section Starts Here!-->
      <button class="contactme">CONTACT ME</button>
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com/link" alt="Twitter"><img class="icons" src="icons/twitter.png"></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/link" alt="LinkedIn"><img class="icons" src="icons/linkedin.png"></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/link" alt="Instagram"><img class="icons" src="icons/instagram.png"></a>
      <!-- Button Section End Here!-->
    </div>

    <div class="AboutMe">
      <p><span style_disabled="color:white">ABOUT ME</span></p>
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I encourage you to find a good editor, or at least use an HTML validator. You have content outside the head and body elements, which is invalid. You're using long-obsolete vendor prefixes for [transition](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition), you have invalid unitless values for things like margin, and you're using line breaks for spacing, which is a misapplication of [the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br). There are many free, high quality editors to be had. They'll help you spot the errors of your ways.

Comment: The demo above doesn't show any horizontal scrollbars. Please edit your post and update that to show the problem. Also see [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: Another tip: Don't use inline styles, _especially_ if you already have a stylesheet. They make your life (and ours) more difficult.

Comment: Regarding your actual question... absolute position is fraught. Don't use it unless you know you need it. Even without that rule, though, the problem isn't apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntroBox position: fixed makes intro box get displayed in a fixed position, independent of other page elements. so when you add AboutMe, its like there is no other div there and it gets rendered at top of page.
to solve this problem you can either use a different style for IntroBox like:

```
    div.IntroBox {
        margin-top: 19vh;
        margin-left: 9%;
        width: 370px;
        padding: 50px;
    }
```

or make AboutMe fixed too (which i don't really recommand):

```
    div.AboutMe {
        left: 10%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 70%;
        padding: 50px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make introBox position:relative

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

/*This section is for the Navigation Bar*/

`.navibar {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Styles the links in the Navigation Bar*/

.navibar a {
  float: right;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Poppins;
}


/*Change the colour of the links and transitions on hover*/

.navibar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline #F1F1F1;
  text-underline-offset: 0.5em;
  transition: 0s;
}


/*Adds decoration, colour, etc. to the active/current link being viewed*/

.navibar a.active {
  text-underline-offset: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: underline #DB6518;
}

body {
  background-color: #070707;
}

div.IntroBox {
  top: 25%;
  left: 10%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
}

p.greet {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Poppins;
}

p.followupgreet {
  margin-top: -20;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #427FBA;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Poppins;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

p.followupgreet:hover {
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Firefox Transition out */
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Opera Transition out */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Safari and Google Chrome Transition out */
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Internet Explorer Transition out */
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Transition for All */
  color: #DB6518;
}

button.contactme {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #070707;
  border: 2px solid #F1F1F1;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  font-family: Poppins;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -5;
}

button.contactme:hover {
  background-color: #427FBA;
  border: 2px solid #366DA3;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Firefox Transition out */
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Opera Transition out */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Safari and Google Chrome Transition out */
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Internet Explorer Transition out */
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  /* Transition for All */
}

img.icons {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 5;
  margin-right: 0;
}

img.icons:hover {
  filter: invert(50%) sepia(9%) saturate(2890%) hue-rotate(168deg) brightness(90%) contrast(93%);
}

p.followuppara {
  margin-top: -20;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: -10;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  font-family: Poppins;
}

div.AboutMe {
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <script src="?.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the JavaScript file name !-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
    <!-- This is the CSS file name !-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Name Here || Portfolio</title>
    <!-- This is the title of the Homepage !-->
  </head>

  <!-- HEADER BAR HERE !-->
  <div class="navibar">
    <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
    <a href="#link">Projects</a>
  </div>

  <body>

    <!--INTRODUCTION BOX STARTS HERE!-->
    <div class="IntroBox">
      <p class="greet">Hello, my name is..</p>
      <br>
      <p class="followupgreet">Name Here</p>
      <br>
      <p class="followuppara">Welcome to my Journey of Web Development.</p>
      <!--INTRODUCTION BOX END HERE!-->

      <!-- Button Section Starts Here!-->
      <button class="contactme">CONTACT ME</button>
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com/link" alt="Twitter"><img class="icons" src="icons/twitter.png"></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/link" alt="LinkedIn"><img class="icons" src="icons/linkedin.png"></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/link" alt="Instagram"><img class="icons" src="icons/instagram.png"></a>
      <!-- Button Section End Here!-->
    </div>

    <div class="AboutMe">
      <p><span style="color:white">ABOUT ME</span></p>

    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```